How to custom devServer response headers in webpack plugin
I hope set response headers to enable wasm multi cores feature, I set following plugin
const {file} = require('ts-node-lib/dist/file');

class OrtWebpackPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.afterResolvers.tap('OrtWebpackPlugin', (compiler) => {
      const ortAliases = this.getOrtAliases(compiler.context);
      compiler.options.resolve.alias = {
        ...compiler.options.resolve.alias,
        ...ortAliases,
      };
    });

    compiler.hooks.afterResolvers.tap('OrtWebpackPlugin', (compiler) => {
      compiler.options.devServer ||= {}
      compiler.options.devServer.headers = {
        ...compiler.options.devServer.headers,
        ...this.getOrtDevServerHeaders(),
      };
    });
  }

  getOrtAliases(projectPath) {
    const ortAliases = {};
    file
      .ls(`${projectPath}/node_modules/onnxruntime-web/dist`)
      .filter((p) => p.match(/\.wasm$/))
      .forEach((p) => {
        const fn = file.basename(p);
        ortAliases[`onnxruntime-web/dist/${fn}`] = `${projectPath}/node_modules/onnxruntime-web/dist/${fn}`;
      });
    return ortAliases;
  }

  getOrtDevServerHeaders() {
    return {
      'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 'require-corp',
      'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin',
    };
  }
}

module.exports.OrtWebpackPlugin = OrtWebpackPlugin

but my dev server page response headers have no cross-origin headers
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 03 Apr 2024 03:20:38 GMT
ETag: W/"24a-ovRrFPNnl1X4YaKmqq9SLwbCdt0"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
X-Powered-By: Express

I'm sure add headers in webpack.config.js devServer directly will work, I guess I use wrong compiler.hooks in my plugin, how to fix it
